# java variable change not applied during synchronous processing

Tags: java, synchronous

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class Test extends Thread {
    private boolean running;
    private Lock cleanupLock;
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        cleanupLock.lock();
        while (running) {
            System.out.println("running!");
        }
        cleanupLock.unlock();
    }

    private void cleanup() {
        running = false;
        cleanupLock.lock(); //wait for thread
        System.out.println("cleanup!");
    }

    public Test() {
         running = true;
         cleanupLock = new ReentrantLock();
         this.start();
         cleanup();
    }

    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        new Test();
    }
}
```

I wrote the code as above.

The result I expected was:

> running! (many times) 
> cleanup!

but when I ran it I got:

> running! (many times)

and it didn't stop.

So, I added `System.out.println(running);` to the while statement.

It was printed as expected.

Wonder why this is happening.
Curious how to fix it.

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer. We do not allow the solution to be edited into the question body.

Comment: Changing your question makes all of the answers wrong.  It defeats the whole purpose of Stack Overflow, which is a Q/A site.  Please don't do this in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It keeps running because there is nothing to tell the started thread that the main thread changed the variable. The change by the main thread isn’t visible to the other thread.

The reason it works when you add println because both threads are using and synchronizing on the console print writer, introducing a happens-before relationship that makes the variable update visible.

You can make the running variable volatile and that will make the change visible without the println.

Answer (score -1):

If we forgot the fact the `running` is not initialized to `true` (which was updated in question), that is a normal behavior from what I'm reading and from what you observe:

> The result I expected was:
>
> ```
> running! (many times)
> cleanup!
> ```
>
> **but when I ran it I got:**
>
> ```
> running! (many times)
> ```
>
> **and it didn't stop.**

- The Thread you start is **owning** the lock.
- The main thread (calling your `Thread`) is made dormant until the other thread release its lock. From the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#lock()) of lock(): *If the lock is held by another thread then the current thread becomes disabled for thread scheduling purposes and lies dormant until the lock has been acquired, at which time the lock hold count is set to one.*
- Because the main thread is in dormant step, the cleanup method is never called and `running` is never set to false.

I can say it is blocked because you observed that `cleanup` was never output. If the main thread acquired the lock, cleanup would be output, and because the lock is before the loop condition, the `running!` would not be output.

This is from your observation, however, it is true that either thread may acquire lock before the other.

As I don't know what you try to achieve, I can only tell that you should have an exit condition in your loop... And you may change exit condition from external thread (with synchronization) only if you don't block it.

Beside, you should lock using try/finally, especially if operation can fail since it may block indefinitely by keeping a lock that should not be kept:

```
  lock.lock();
  try {
    ...
  } finally {
    lock.unlock(); 
  }
```

Comment: This is incorrect.  The `cleanup` method sets `running` BEFORE it tries to obtain the lock.  The logic there is just fine.  It is true that the `run` method will never print anything, but the fact that `running` is never set to `true` does not affect the lockup.

Comment: I updated my answer with a quote. I never said that the main thread never acquired the lock in some case, I only said that in the observation the OP made, the started thread acquired the lock. My answer is not wrong.